# redirect user to login page without using fbml on facebook page

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, fbml

so i'm creating a login_url using php framework and `getLoginUrl()`.

if my facebook app is setted as an FBML page, something like this works fine

```
echo '<fb:redirect url="'.$login_url.'" />';
```

but i need my facebook application configured as an IFRAME page, so it will not be rendered as FBML.

whats the best way to redirect my user to the login page?

using `header();` in php will not work, because header is already sent. also

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript"> document.setLocation("'.$login_url.'"); </script>';
```

has no effect.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at the moment

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript"> top.location.href = "'.$login_url.'"; </script>';
```

is working. but i think its not a very clean solution.
i'll accept another answer if somebody has a better way.

Comment: This is the correct solution per Facebook's developer documentation.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/